# Simplifying this expression with Gamma

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

The `Gamma` function has the property that $\Gamma(z+1)=\Gamma(z)z$, so this expression:

```
( Sqrt[Gamma[1 + l - m]] Sqrt[Gamma[2 + l + m]] )/(Sqrt[ Gamma[l - m]] Sqrt[Gamma[1 + l + m]])
```

should simplify to something like $\sqrt{(l-m)(l+m+1)}$ (if I am not mistaken), but `FullSimplify` with the `Assumption` that `l` and `m` are integers does not simplify it.

How can I simplify that expression?

Comment: It seems that you play with rules of calculating angular momentum in quantum mechanics. Anyway it might be interesting if you add  a context where from your expression come out.

Comment: @Artes, indeed, it almost looks like a ratio of the prefactors for spherical harmonics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For non-positive integers `Gamma` takes `ComplexInfinity` value, and so

```
FullSimplify[( Sqrt[Gamma[1 + l - m]] Sqrt[Gamma[2 + l + m]] )/(
               Sqrt[ Gamma[l - m]] Sqrt[Gamma[1 + l + m]]),
              (l|m) \[Element] Integers && l >= m>= 0]
```

> ```
>   Sqrt[(l - m)(1 + l + m)]
> ```

Comment: A simpler command `FullSimplify[a, Assumptions -> l - m > 0 && l + m > -1]` works here.

Comment: @user64494 Mind your strong inequality, while the weak also is true.  Nevertheless you should know what `l` and `m` means in quantum mechanics and why they are integer.

Comment: @ Artes, you are not right: my assumptions  are weaker than tours. A simpler example is  `x>0` is weaker than `x\[Element] Integers &&x>0`. Hope I am clear, however, don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: @user64494  They are not, you exclude the case `l == m == 0` and since you don't understand my first comment, better back to school.

Comment: @Atrtes:Thank you. The assumptions `Assumptions -> l - m >= 0 && l + m >= -1`  also works  here. The value of `Gamma[0]` is `ComplexInfinity` and arithmetic with `ComplexIinfinity` is not defined in complex analysis.

Comment: I'd like to add that `FunctionDomain[Gamma[z], z]` produces $z>0\lor z\notin \mathbb{Z}$ and `FunctionDomain[Gamma[z], z, Complexes]` results in $\Re(z)>0\lor z\notin \mathbb{Z}$. One cannot simplify an undefined expression.

Comment: @user64494   The question does not consider the domain of  `Gamma` but rather of an expression involving `Gamma`,  infinity in the denominator is not harmful and the expression itself is well defined for `l == m`.  Any polemics with you is a waste of time.

Comment: Artes, I prefer arguments over emotional words. BTW, several bug reports on that topic are prepared by me.

Comment: @user64494 My arguments are emotional sometimes, this is not bad.  You comments  however are pointless. If you have something to add you should provide another answer or upvote this one.  Since you've done neither this nor that I guess you are ill.  My  expectation is that you shouldn't litter up this site with invaluable comments.  Nethertheless If they are, just provide another answer and persuade others that you have something constructive to say.  You could not persuade me, perhaps  you will be successful with others.